# What is the correct syntax for using 'arrive' with a destination?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which should I say?

> I arrive to my work.

or

> I arrive into my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we use "at" and sometimes we use "to".  If what follows the preposition is action-like or an ongoing event, then we can use "to" or "at".

He arrived at 8AM.

They police arrived at the just right moment to thwart the bank robbery.

The police arrived at the scene of the crime.

He arrived to work drunk, and got fired.

They arrived late to the wedding.

Comment: Really, Tim? AmE allows "arrived to work drunk"? Well I never. As a Brit I would never say that. Arrive at work, or more likely "came to work drunk". I would also arrive at a wedding, or arrive late for the wedding.

Comment: Seems so. Arrived to work. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arrived+to+work&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carrived%20to%20work%3B%2Cc0)  Late to the party. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arrived+late+to+the+party&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carrived%20late%20to%20the%20party%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 4):

Neither. You arrive *at* your work.

> [arrive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arrive) (v) - Reach a place at the end of a journey or a stage in a journey:
>   *we arrived at his house and knocked at the door*

Comment: Is it at used for time?

Comment: @Maythux Not always. You can arrive *at 7.00pm*, also *by 7.00pm*, *before 7.00pm* or *after 7.00pm*. You can also arrive *before/after John*, or *before/after the meeting had started*.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough,"to arrive" is not considered a verb expressing movement. So you shouldn't use any prepositions of movement ( to,into ), but only the static ones ( in,at ).

Answer (score 1):

You may also say "arrive for work", meaning "arrive ready for work" with Ready understood.